# React Modal ref Undefined! Can't Add Custom Attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-bootstrap, react-dom

I have a simple modal:

```
renderModalForm() {
    return (
      <Modal
        closeTimeoutMS={150}
        show={this.state.isModalOpen}
        onHide={this.isModalOpen.bind(this)}
      >
        <Modal.Body>
          <div className="close-button-modal">
            <i className="fa fa-times fa-2x pull-right" onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)}></i>
            <div className="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div ref="test" className="testclassname">
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
```

My sole objective is to inject a custom attribute (which unfortunately cannot start with data- or aria- since it's defined by third party) to the `div` referenced by `ref="test"`

When I attempt to inject the custom attribute:

```
someButtonClicked() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        isModalOpen: true
      })
    }, 100);
    var element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.test);
    element.setAttribute('doku-div', 'form-payment');
}
```

Here element is always undefined, so `setAttribute` failed; if I go inspect the element, `ref="test"` does not exist at the `<div>` ! Can someone help me as to why this ref is missing inside modal?

Comment: so the setState to open the modal is actually called inside a buttonClickHandler method as well.. So I can't move it inside componentDidMount

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to implement is use Callback hook. Whenever the component will render you will have the ref element. useCallback will also help stop unnecessary renders hence better performance.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsVisible(!isVisible)}>Show/Hide Popup</button>
      <Child isVisible={isVisible} />
    </>
  );
};

const Child = () => {
  const customRef = useCallback((ref) => {
    // ref element accessible here
  }, []);
  return (
    <Modal show={isVisible}>
      <Modal.Body>
        <input ref={customRef} type="text" />
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code to `ComponentDidMount` or `ComponentDidUpdate` method. Refs shouldn't be undefined there.

You can also use a callback to store a reference to the DOM node:

```
<Modal.Body>
          <div className="close-button-modal">
            <i className="fa fa-times fa-2x pull-right" onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)}></i>
            <div className="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div ref="{(testNode) => { this.testNode = testNode; }}" className="testclassname">
          </div>
</Modal.Body>
```

And then use that reference instead of using ReactDOM:

```
someButtonClicked() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          isModalOpen: true
        })
    }, 100);

    var element = this.testNode;
    this.testNode.setAttribute('doku-div', 'form-payment');
}
```

Comment: so the setState to open the modal is actually called inside a buttonClickHandler method as well.. So I can't move it inside componentDidMount, editing the question for clarification

Comment: You can use `this.testNode` which contains a reference to the DOM element in your click handler

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but ref is still not rendered :(... Also, I can't put the code inside componentDidMount, because the Modal + its children are not even rendered when it's hidden / not opened in the beginning.. I think it's only rendered when I do setState({isModalOpen: true})... but the problem still remains.. ref is missing :X

Comment: Have you tried using `componentDidUpdate`? It seems like Modal.Body is not rendered when `someButtonClicked` is executed. It would be useful if you create a jsfiddle with your component.

Comment: so when i do inspect element, i was able to see the Modal.Body rendered, i can even see data-custom-attribute if i set it, but no ref... so stuck :X

Comment: @user1955934 ref is an attribute of the virtual DOM, you will not see this attribute when you inspect the DOM. Try using React Developer Tools. 

Check that you are not accessing ref before the child component has been mounted

Comment: I added console.log(this.refs) just after the setTimeout(() => {this.setState({ isModalOpen: true }) }, 100);  but it's printing empty object, which means ref is not there. I was expecting a short while after the setState is called, modal children are mounted

Answer (score 0):

useRef hook will not work in modals as the component will mount but the jsx will not render until you make show prop to true. useRef is asynchronous in nature thats why at the time of declaration it sets current to null but after you assign it to any element ref got value of it. But in case of modals the case is different. Here the elements are not registered instantly but after modal show prop is set to true

To solve this make the modal's show prop always to true and make whole component to show/hide dynamically
[similar query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479879/refs-are-always-null-inside-modal-component/69222037#69222037)