# Refs are always null inside modal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

All refs created inside the reactstrap modal component are null inside compoenentDIDMount no matter how they are created

This is related to react-dom version 16.8.6.  I have tried assigning ref directly, using react.createRef(), and callbacks.

```
import { Modal, Form } from 'reactstrap'

class QuickBidModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isOpen: false,
        };
        this.input1 = React.createRef();
    }

componentDidMount(){
  console.log(this.input1) //Always returns current as null
}

render(){
 <Modal>
  <Form>
  <div className="input" ref={this.input1} />
  </Form>

 </Modal>
}
```

I expect this.input1 to be of class input on the current property.  However, it only returns null.  If I create the div element OUTSIDE of the Modal component, then the ref works properly.

Comment: It seems that the library doesn't take into accounts ref passed to its children. it must do some kind of cloning to add some custom props, try checking the documentation if you can pass additional props to its children.

Comment: And here is the source code : https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/Form.js as you can see there is no 'this.props.children' so it means that this package doesn't take into account children so the real question is : what exactly do you can to achieve ?

If we look at the source code they always take the tag props and use it as a react element. so Maybe you can simply pass the tag props with a ref to it.

Comment: @MaieonBrix They use object spread syntax to put the rest of the props (`children` included) into the `attributes` variable, which is being applied to the component under the alias `Tag`. So the `Tag` component should have `children`.

Comment: indeed ! thanks @Rallen, then maybe we could use the innerRef props ?

Answer (score 3):

Method provided by @Ayush singh is more like a hack. The correct way to implement is use Callback hook. Whenever the component will render you will have the ref element. useCallback will also help stop unnecessary renders hence better performance.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsVisible(!isVisible)}>Show/Hide Popup</button>
      <Child isVisible={isVisible} />
    </>
  );
};

const Child = () => {
  const customRef = useCallback((ref) => {
    // ref element accessible here
  }, []);
  return (
    <Modal show={isVisible}>
      <Modal.Body>
        <input ref={customRef} type="text" />
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why did no one upvote this? Thanks @Saqy G

Comment: Probably because you posted it 2 years after the original question and one year after the other answer that you're referencing - if it makes you feel better, Im going to use your method :)

Answer (score 1):

useRef hook will not work in modals as the component will mount but the jsx will not render until you make show prop to true. useRef is asynchronous in nature thats why at the time of declaration it sets current to null but after you assign it to any element ref got value of it. But in case of modals the case is different. Here the elements are not registered instantly but after modal show prop is set to true

To solve this make the modal's show prop always to true and make whole component to show/hide dynamically. eg.

```
const Child=()=>{
  const customRef=useRef(null);
  return(
     <Modal show={true}>
       <Modal.Body>
         <input ref={customRef} type="text"/>
       </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
   );
}

const Parent=()=>{
   const [show,setShow]=useState=(false)
   return(
       <>
         <button onClick={()=>setShow(!show)}>Show/Hide Popup</button>
         {
           show?<Child/>:null
         }
       </>
   )
  }
```